# Jackson JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

Just updated Spring boot (to 3.2) and Java (to 21) of an existing project and started to have problems with Jackson (updated to version 2.15.3)

The problem is with classes that implement interface and use `JsonTypeIdResolver`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "screen",
    visible = true
)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(BaseFilterResolver::class)
interface BaseFilter: ProjectFilter {
    val id: Long?
    val screen: Screen
}

data class Screen1Filter(
        override val id: Long? = null,
        val period: Period?,
        //... other properties
        override val screen: Screen = Screen.SCREEN1
): BaseFilter {...}



class BaseFilterResolver : TypeIdResolverBase() {
    private var superType: JavaType? = null
    override fun init(baseType: JavaType?) {
        superType = baseType
    }

    override fun idFromValue(obj: Any): String? {
        return null
    }

    override fun idFromValueAndType(obj: Any?, subType: Class<*>): String? {
        return null
    }

    override fun typeFromId(context: DatabindContext, id: String?): JavaType {
        return context.constructSpecializedType(superType, Screen.values().find { it.name == id }!!.filterClass)
    }

    override fun getMechanism(): JsonTypeInfo.Id {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM;
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
ObjectMapperService.objectMapperForFilters.writeValueAsString(Screen1Filter(...))
```

I get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

The searialization works for other objects that does not have the configuration with `@JsonTypeIdResolver`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue under pretty much identical circumstances and resolved it by returning empty string `""` in idFromValue and idFromValueAndType.